# Mobile navigation is shown, but standard navigation does not disappear

Tags: menus, navigation

I have setup that website berlin-permanent-makeup.de and the mobile navigation kicks in, as soon as the screen is smaller than 800 px wide.

So far, so good. My problem is, the standard navigation does not disappear.

That means, I have now the same navigation twice. Once in ugly broken words, once in the mobile button menu.

You can see for yourself on the above-mentioned link.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you should try below

```
.nav-holder { display: none; }
```

on media.css line no. 115

Comment: I do not have a media.css, just the style.css, but I did use a media query with the display:none feature. Thanks.